# Is it true, that $\lim_{x \to \infty} {\bigg(\frac {\int_a^b{g^{x}(t)dt}}{b - a}\bigg)}^{\frac {1}{x}} = max(g(t))$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Is the statement, that $\lim_{x \to \infty} {\bigg(\frac {\int_a^b{g^{x}(t)dt}}{b - a}\bigg)}^{\frac {1}{x}} = max(g(t))$, where max(g(t)) is the maximal value, taken by function g(t) on [a, b], true for each real-valued function g(t), that is continuous on [a, b] and takes only positive values on it?

I could neither prove it, nor find any counterexamples to it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Consider $g(t)=1$ for $t=a$ and otherwise $g(t)=0$. Then $g$ is Rieman-integrable on $[a,b]$ with $\int_a^b g^x(t)~dt = 0$ for all $x$. Therefore the limit yields $0$ although the maximum of $g$ is $1$. The links from Clement are quite good. The setting for you functions are important. In my example $g$ is not continious. And if you consider measurable functions, you should use the essential maximum of a function, which is $0$ in my example and doesn't yield a contradition.

Comment: (removed my links, they were on the right panel: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2047500/prove-that-lim-n-to-infty-bigg-int-01ftn-textdt-bigg1-n-m?rq=1, and an "essential supremum see as a limit" question)

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to write that this g(t) is continuous. Now I will correct my error.